# How to call Planning Wizard in MS Project 2007 add-in's C# code to resolve tasks' date conflicts?

Tags: c#, add-in, ms-project

In Microsoft Project 2007, when setting a task's start date field to a nonworking day, a Planning Wizard (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftyha.png) shows up. The user can choose how to resolve this conflict. The options are changing the date to a working day or declaring the day as a working day.

Is it possible to call this Planning Wizard in C# code? I'm working on an add-in that makes changes to tasks' start fields and I'd prefer not to write additional forms for these conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to call any of the "green corner" dialogs either from VBA or through COM interfaces.

When you do something with tasks in a project through MS Project API you have to keep in mind default behavior: e.g. what parameter is changing by default when you change a duration of fixed duration task and so on.

The easiest way to solve the "weekend start" problem is use 7 days/week calendar and if task should start on weekend - just assign the calendar to the task: TaskCalendar field of a Task object.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that those dialogs can't be called. Modifying the (task) calendar is what I have in mind. But since date changes can occur for an arbitrary number of tasks, the user must be notified and guided to avoid confusion. Again, thank you very much!